# How to use sort command with ioredis?

Tags: javascript, redis, ioredis

```
await ioredis.sort(
    itemsByViewsKey(),
    "BY",
    "nosort",
    "LIMIT",
    0,
    10,
    "GET",
    `${itemsKey("*")}->name`,
    `${itemsKey("*")}->views`,
    order
  );
```

I want to sort the above logic by `nosort`, then add limit with the provided offset and count and Get the name and views. This produces this error message:

```
error - ReplyError: ERR unknown command `sort_ro`, with args beginning with: `items:views`, `BY`, `nosort`, `LIMIT`, `0`, `10`, `GET`, `items#*->name`, `items#*->views`, `DESC`, 
    at parseError (/Users/transformhub/Desktop/VID/Redis/rbay/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:179:12)
    at parseType (/Users/transformhub/Desktop/VID/Redis/rbay/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:302:14) {
  command: {
    name: 'sort_ro',
    args: [
      'items:views',
      'BY',
      'nosort',
      'LIMIT',
      '0',
      '10',
      'GET',
      'items#*->name',
      'items#*->views',
      'DESC'
    ]
  },
  page: '/api/itemsByViews'
}
```

I also tried `sort_ro` but I still get an error saying:

```
error - ReplyError: ERR unknown command `sort_ro`, with args beginning with: `items:views`, `BY`, `nosort`, `LIMIT`, `0`, `10`, `GET`, `items#*->name`, `items#*->views`, `DESC`, 
    at parseError (/Users/transformhub/Desktop/VID/Redis/rbay/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:179:12)
    at parseType (/Users/transformhub/Desktop/VID/Redis/rbay/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:302:14) {
  command: {
    name: 'sort_ro',
    args: [
      'items:views',
      'BY',
      'nosort',
      'LIMIT',
      '0',
      '10',
      'GET',
      'items#*->name',
      'items#*->views',
      'DESC'
    ]
  },
  page: '/api/itemsByViews'
}
```

The is unclear on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just test this code with some sample data I created. It seems to do as you wish:

```
const Redis = require("ioredis")
const redis = new Redis()

const redisDemo = async () => {

        // Creating the entries
        await redis.hset("items_1", "name", "orange")
        await redis.hset("items_1", "views", "34")

        await redis.hset("items_2", "name", "apple")
        await redis.hset("items_2", "views", "12")

        // Add the ids to a list
        await redis.lpush('ids', 1)
        await redis.lpush('ids', 2)

        // Sort using the ratings
        res = await redis.sort('ids', "BY", "nosort",
                "LIMIT", 0, 10,
                "GET", "items_*->name",
                "GET", "items_*->views",
                "desc")
        console.log(res)
};

// Call demo
redisDemo();
```

But to know for sure, I'd need to have some sample data (2 items like my sample data).

The main item I noticed when testing is you need a `GET` for every result. You are missing one:

```
  'GET',
  'items#*->name',
  'items#*->views',
```